# How many strains of influenza can occupy a person at one time?

Tags: cell-biology, microbiology, immunology, virology

Could a person's immune system be built eventually to be able to inject all the known strains with in to stay immune?

Comment: Your premise is wrong to begin with. It's absolutely not true that everybody eventually catches the flu.

Comment: Please edit your title so that it gives a better indication of what aspect of influenza it concerns. This saves people time and, unless this question is removed (as being hypothetical), is more useful for indexing.

Comment: @David revised...

Comment: @TimonG. - Your comment is incorrect. Eventually, indeed, most people will catch the flu (Influenza A or B). It is the rare individual who will have never, ever contracted any strain of influenza. Up to 30% of the infected are assymptomatic, and the odds of being infected any given year are from about 1:10. (Range: 1:20 to 1:5.) If you live 20 years, your odds of never having gotten the flu are about 2 in 100. What are your numbers?

Comment: That what I initially thought I had. I changed it because if an answer. I am talking about intentionally on a safely way of taking all the strains numbers aside.

Comment: Hypothetical questions are often sub-par due to the absence of information on the part of th OP. However, the worst part of this question is "Could my blood be used to help others recover or would it be lethal?" Why in heaven's name would it be lethal? Are you dead from it?

Comment: @assymptomatic because I would be asymptomatic and contagious and not immune.

Comment: @anongoodnurse You are mistaking the notion that everybody catches the flu eventually with the concept that the average person gets the flu eventually. The latter is correct, the former is not. Even your choice of numbers (which I did check and are approximately in the right ball park but you are ignoring re-infections in your calculation) yield millions and millions of people who will never get the flu. I want to note that OP edited his comment to "most" people only now after my comment. OP originally stated flat out that *everybody* gets it and that is false even acc. to your numbers.

Comment: We seem to also disagree on what it means to have the flu. Being exposed to the influenza virus is being exposed to the influenza virus. Flu is the label for the disease which is caused by the influenza virus, not a label for the influenza virus itself. If a person has the influenza virus in their bodies but absolutely no symptoms, I consider it confused and incorrect to state that they have the flu. Diseases are sets of conditions and symptoms, not the mere presence of a pathogen that your immune system is fighting off. This is similar to the distinction between being HIV+ and having AIDS.

Comment: @TimonG. - I never said everybody catches the flu. Read more carefully both my statement and the OP's. Also, if you are asymptomatically infected with influenza virus, you have caught the flu. Again, where are your numbers?

Comment: OP literally said "Eventually you will catch the flu." in the first version of his question, check his edit history. That was what I originally replied to. OP then edited his question after my comment to instead say "Eventually most will catch the flu.". That is a completely different claim and I already explained this in the previous comments. It doesn't do you any good to be confrontational and accuse me of not reading when you yourself haven't done so.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to edit your question to be more clear, @Muze. There is nothing wrong with that. Perhaps in the future a small edit note at the bottom will help people.

Comment: where do i find a list of influenza strain weak to worst?

Comment: @Muze - if you try ordering some of the bad strains of influenza, you'll very quickly find yourself being visited by large, serious men with bad haircuts and suits. This is not a good idea to follow up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is whether being exposed "to all strains of influenza" would make one immune to all strains of influenza. No, and it's not possible to expose oneself to all strains of influenza in the first place.

It might be technically possible to expose yourself to all *subtypes* of influenza, if you limited to the hemagglutinin subtypes, of which there are 18. But subtypes are not strains; a strain is an antigenic variant of a subtype, and there are tens of thousands of such variants. Even if you somehow managed to expose yourself to every known strain, presumably by injecting yourself every few hours for years (you probably don't want to literally expose yourself to all the strains of flu, because some of them have mortality rates well over 50%, so you'd be dead before you were immune), new strains arise literally every minute of every day.

And because of vagaries of the immune system that are too complex to get into here, immunity to some strains *prevents* immunity to some others (one review is [Immune history and influenza virus susceptibility](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1879625716302127?via%3Dihub)), so it's either very difficult, or perhaps intrinsically impossible, to get complete immunity.

There's work being done on overcoming these problems with "universal" influenza vaccines, and your best bet is to wait until some of these are available.

Comment: I had no idea that immunity to some strains can prevent immunity to others! Nice to learn something new!